# Implement ROW_NUMBER() in beamSQL

Tags: apache-beam

I have the below query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Summed, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (order by Summed desc) as Rank  from table1
```

I have to write it in Apache Beam(beamSql). Below is my code :

```
PCollection<BeamRecord> rec_2_part2 = rec_2.apply(BeamSql.query("SELECT DISTINCT Summed, ROW_NUMBER(Summed) OVER (ORDER BY Summed) Rank1 from PCOLLECTION "));
```

But I'm getting the below error :

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Operator: ROW_NUMBER is not supported yet!

Any idea how to implement ROW_NUMBER() in beamSql ?

Comment: I created a Jira to implement ROW_NUMBER: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-4509 .

If this feature is high priority for you and you want to make sure it gets attention soon, then you could work on it yourself, Beam community will appreciate the contribution: https://beam.apache.org/contribute/

If you do want to look at it, then you can start from here, this is the place where Beam SQL dispatches operators: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/extensions/sql/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/sql/impl/interpreter/BeamSqlFnExecutor.java#L482

Comment: Did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which worked for the above query:

```
PCollection<BeamRecord> rec_2 = rec_1.apply(BeamSql.query("SELECT max(Summed) as maxed, max(Summed)-10 as least, 'a' as Dummy from PCOLLECTION"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can approximate your current query without using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    t1.Summed,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Summed FROM table1) t2
     WHERE t2.Summed >= t1.Summed) AS Rank
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Summed
    FROM table1
) t1
```

The basic idea is to first subquery to get a table with only distinct `Summed` values.  Then, use a correlated subquery to simulate the row number.  This isn't a very efficient method, but if `ROW_NUMBER` is not available, then you're stuck with some alternative.

Comment: Thanks Tim.. But I dont think I can implement something of this format in beam SQL. I even tried using 'Order by' but that is also doesn't supported in beamSQL.